# What does the regular expression ^$ evaluate to?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I really haven't been able to figure out this regular expression. I do know that

- `^` means starts with
- `$` means ends with

But when you combine the two I really don't understand what would this evaluate to. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It evaluates to an empty string.

If you add the `m` flag, as in `/^$/m`, it matches an empty line. [**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yS1oZ5/1).